# How can I have human-readable key names in a configuration file?

Tags: c++, input, file-format, control, settings

Given a file mapping keys to controls, such as this:

```
up         w
down       s
left       a
right      d
jump   space
run    shift
crouch  ctrl
```

The values need to be converted into game commands, and constants. The commands aren't so much a problem as the keyboard keys are; a keyboard can contain over 100 keys, so the last thing desired is this:

```
unsigned int pressedKey;
if (value == "a") {
    pressedKey = KEY_A;
} else if (value == "b") {
    pressedKey = KEY_B;
} else if (value == "c") {
    pressedKey = KEY_C;
} else if...
```

What comes to mind would be to build a map of key value pairs, something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> keyFinder;
keyFinder.emplace("a", KEY_A);
keyFinder.emplace("b", KEY_B);
keyFinder.emplace("c", KEY_C);
// and so on
```

This would allow for fast lookups, but on the downside it still has to be hardcoded, and it's not going to be a pretty segment of code.

I'd love to hear some good solutions for reading a file and using it to map controls! If it involves using some other file format, that's fine too, as long as it's human readable.

Comment: I think this question would fit better on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) than Gamedev. Regardless, if you're trying to cast a char to an unsigned int, check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893128/how-can-i-cast-a-char-to-an-unsigned-int).

Comment: I disagree; this seems reasonably game development focused. I also don't believe that SO thread really has anything to do with what the asker is looking for.

Comment: Why does "human readable" matter?  GUI or bust, preferably in-game.  Even of the format is easy, the values are not: is it Spave or space or " " or what?  PrintScreen or PrntScrn or "Print Screen"?  Esc or Escape?  How do you write out analog controls?  Key conbinations?  Gestures?  Use a GUI, don't care if the format is human readable.

Comment: What is your engine or framework? It probably provides this functionality already. Otherwise, what's wrong with hardcoding the mapping? It's not like keyboards change *that* often.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch The "final" product will definitely have the aforementioned GUI. Until then, though, I plan on having a default set of keybindings. If someone testing the game wants to modify those defaults, I'll point them towards the file (and a README).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. I think you should use a map (like your `unordered_map` example). And you should just hard code the entire map like you suggested:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> keyFinder;
keyFinder.emplace("a", KEY_A);
keyFinder.emplace("b", KEY_B);
keyFinder.emplace("c", KEY_C);
keyFinder.emplace("ctrl", KEY_CONTROL);
keyFinder.emplace("shift", KEY_SHIFT);
// ...
```

It's *much* easier and cleaner than correctly identifying the textual equivalents of all possible keys on all possible keyboards in a standard way. Keyboards are very *complicated*.

You *can* programmatically produce the mapping from key code to key text. On Windows, for example, iterate over every [virtual key code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), call [`MapVirtualKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to translate to scan codes, then call [`GetKeyNameText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are similar processes for other operating systems. However, the key text you get back is set by the keyboard driver *and* translated based on the locale settings in almost all cases. This makes the data unreliable for use in configuration files.

A technique like the above *can* be useful for displaying the actual keys that a user should press (for example as part of an on-screen prompt), but not for producing a reliable textual mapping. Consequently, I think you are better off just hard-coding your desired mapping. Once you have this mapping to key names, put your key-name-to-action mappings in a JSON/XML/YAML/whatever-text-based-format-your-prefer file.

(Note that on some OSs, like Windows, the virtual key codes for A - Z map to the ASCII values for uppercase A - Z, so you can save yourself *some* typing there; you can find similarly exploitable patterns with numbers and F-keys, usually).

---

All of that said, I do agree with Sean's comment that you can avoid the need for this mapping entirely by providing good GUI support for adjusting keyboard bindings; then you can store out the locale-agnostic key values (virtual key codes on Windows) into your configuration file.